# How to sum elements of 2 or more arrays in Mongo

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I'm new to mongo/nosql have multiple documents with the same array structure in item "VALUES".  I'd like to be able to sum each element position of 2 or more arrays.  Thanks for the help!

*Arrays*

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54cbf4e6e883561eba48425e"),
    "NAME" : "ATest",
    "VALUES" : [
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4,
        5
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54cbf4e6e883561eba4842b4"),
    "NAME" : "BTest",
    "VALUES" : [
        10,
        20,
        30,
        40,
        50
    ]
}
```

*Desired Result*

```
{
    "_id" : "SUMTest",
    "SUMVALUES" : [
        11,
        22,
        33,
        44,
        55
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would be tough as an aggregation, but try [map reduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/) and emit each value with the index as the id. Something like:

```
mapReduce(
  function m() {
    this.VALUES.forEach(function (value, index) {
      emit(index, value)
    })
  },
  function r(id, values) {
    return Array.sum(values)
  },
  {
    query: {}
  }
)
```